# VPN IPSEC PSK NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, 18.10

In Ubuntu 18.10, I'm trying to set-up a L2TP VPN connection with a WatchGuard server using PSK with SHA1-AES 256bit DH group 2 for Phase 1 and ESP-AES-SHA1 group 1 for Phase 2.

I tried with both Strongswan and Libreswan but always get a NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error, no matter which algorithms I choose in ipsec.conf or in GNOME network manager. Relevant files are shown below. What do you suggest?

ipsec.conf

```
conn vpn
authby=secret
left=%defaultroute
leftxauthclient=yes
leftmodecfgclient=yes
leftxauthusername=[MY USERNAME]
modecfgpull=yes
right=[SERVER IP]
rightxauthserver=yes
rightmodecfgserver=yes
rekey=no
auto=add
ike_frag=no
ike=aes256-sha-modp2048
esp=aes-sha1-modp1024
```

ipsec.secrets

```
[MY SERVER IP] %any : PSK "[MY PSK]"
@[MY USERNAME] : XAUTH "[MY PASSWORD]"
```

**edit** new ipsec.conf:

```
conn myvpn
ikelifetime=8h
keylife=20m
rekeymargin=3m
keyingtries=3
keyexchange=ikev1
authby=psk 
left=%defaultroute
auto=add
authby=secret
type=transport
leftprotoport=17/1701
rightprotoport=17/1701
right=[SERVER_IP]
dpdtimeout=120
dpdaction=clear
rekey=yes
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes256-sha1-modp768!
```

launching `ipsec -up myvpn` gives:

```
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA myvpn[1] to [SERVER_IP]
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
sending packet: from 192.168.1.6[500] to [SERVER_IP][500] (180 bytes)
received packet: from [SERVER_IP][500] to 192.168.1.6[500] (136 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V ]
received XAuth vendor ID
received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
received DPD vendor ID
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
sending packet: from 192.168.1.6[500] to [SERVER_IP][500] (244 bytes)
received packet: from [SERVER_IP][500] to 192.168.1.6[500] (220 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH N(INITIAL_CONTACT) ]
sending packet: from 192.168.1.6[4500] to [SERVER_IP][4500] (108 bytes)
received packet: from [SERVER_IP][4500] to 192.168.1.6[4500] (76 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]
IKE_SA myvpn[1] established between    192.168.1.6[192.168.1.6]...[SERVER_IP][SERVER_IP]
scheduling reauthentication in 28591s
maximum IKE_SA lifetime 28771s
generating QUICK_MODE request 3496213378 [ HASH SA No KE ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
sending packet: from 192.168.1.6[4500] to [SERVER_IP][4500] (300 bytes)
received packet: from [SERVER_IP][4500] to 192.168.1.6[4500] (76 bytes)
parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2157690019 [ HASH N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
establishing connection 'myvpn' failed
```

**edit** 
xl2tpd.conf

```
[lac myvpn]
lns = [SERVER_IP]
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
length bit = yes
```

/etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-chap
noccp
noauth
mtu 1280
mru 1280
noipdefault
defaultroute
usepeerdns
connect-delay 5000
name [MY USERNAME]
password [MY PASSWORD]
```

Trying with network manager returns:

```
nm-l2tp-service[17266]: xl2tpd started with pid 17340
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Using l2tp kernel support.
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.12 started on Ing PID:17340
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Connecting to host [SERVER_IP], port 1701
NetworkManager[1137]: <info>  [1541422442.3462] vpn-connection[0x55a9be8bc370,c657e7cd-7120-40b6-936c-969ca917c53c,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Connection established to [SERVER_IP], 1701.  Local: 62148, Remote: 1 (ref=0/0).
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Calling on tunnel 62148
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: Call established with [SERVER_IP], Local: 47419, Remote: 1, Serial: 1 (ref=0/0)
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: start_pppd: I'm running:
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "plugin"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "pppol2tp.so"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "pppol2tp"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "7"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "passive"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "nodetach"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: ":"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "file"
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: "/run/nm-l2tp-ppp-options-c657e7cd-7120-40b6-936c-969ca917c53c"
pppd[17341]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.
pppd[17341]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-l2tp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
pppd[17341]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
pppd[17341]: Using interface ppp0
    pppd[17341]: Connect: ppp0 <--> 
pppd[17341]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400
pppd[17341]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400
NetworkManager[1137]: <info>  [1541422442.4026] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/19)
systemd-udevd[17344]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
NetworkManager[1137]: <info>  [1541422442.4117] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
NetworkManager[1137]: <info>  [1541422442.4117] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 1 (got 1, expected 2)
NetworkManager[1137]: xl2tpd[17340]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ipsec.conf seems to be for IPsec IKEv1 XAuth, not for L2TP/IPsec, but you mentioned L2TP. What kind of VPN service is the WatchGuard server offering?

If you are using strongswan I would try adding an exclamation mark (!) to the end, also your esp syntax was wrong. Try offering the following proposals in the ipsec.conf file and see if the VPN server is happy :

- ike=aes256-sha1-modp2048!
- esp=aes-sha1!

Comment: aes is an alias for aes128, so I don't know for the Phase 2  or esp line if it should be esp=aes256-sha1!  as it is odd to use a different number of bits between phase 1 & 2. See the following page for the encryption algorithm keywords https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv1CipherSuites

Comment: I'm totally sure the server is offering L2TP with those algorithms.
Following various guides i edited ipsec.conf as shown in my edited question.
Still getting the same error...
What's the difference between a IKEv1 and a L2TP configuration in ipsec.conf?

Comment: L2TP/IPsec is also IKEv1, but uses L2TP (or more precisely PPP) for the user authentication, while IPsec XAuth does the user authentication by itself and doesn't need L2TP. For a L2TP ipsec.conf you would normally find leftprotoport and rightprotoport=udp/L2TP (or =17/1701 if you prefer numerical values like your example), there is no XAuth, there are also config files for xl2tpd and pppd. From the logs IKE Phase 1 has been established, but ESP Quick Mode is failing. I would recommend using esp=aes256-sha1! as it is usually esp=encryption-integrity!

Comment: Connection successful using esp=aes256-sha1!
Thank you very much!
The problem is now with xl2tpd, launching `echo "c myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control` doesn't make available the ppp0 device I expect.

Comment: Or you could use network-manager-l2tp and in the IPsec config dialog box enter aes256-sha1-modp1024! for phase 1 and aes256-sha1! for phase 2. If you do use network-manager-l2tp, you might need to stop the system xl2tpd service, see the README.md file for issue with not stopping system xl2tpd service https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/tree/nm-1-2

Comment: Tried that solution as well, receiving `handle_packet: bad control packet!`.
Updated log in original post

Comment: Regarding "Received out of order control packet on tunnel 1 (got 1, expected 2)", see this xl2tpd Watchguard issue https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd/issues/136

Comment: Tried that as well.
Launching xl2tpd from terminal gives `Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701` and nothing more; launching from Network Manager still gives `bad control packet!`